# Does group $A_6$ contain subgroup isomorphic with $S_4$

Tags: group-theory

Does group $A_6$ contain subgroup isomorphic with $S_4$ ?

The only thing that I ask for is any clue.

Comment: Find an element of order 4 in $A_6$, and a suitable element of order 3 in $A_6$, and see if they don't generate a copy of $S_4$.

Comment: More generally, $A_{n+2}$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $S_n$.

Comment: This otherwise good question has been handled here at least twice. First [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83160/11619) and more recently [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/712847/11619).

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Take $S_4$ on the first four elements of the set permuted by $A_6$. Some of these are odd permutations. Can you see an easy way to convert them into even permutations which are contained in $A_6$? Can you do this in a consistent way which doesn't disturb the $S_4$ structure?

Comment: Ok, slowly, it is difficult for me. Let $G$ will be subgroup of $A_6$ isomorphic to $S_4$. Thus, |G| = $S_4$.  But I still have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Going by Mark's answer's hint, you can prove that in general $\;S_n\;$ is embeddable in $\;A_{n+2}\;$ . Can you find an example when it is not enough to take $\;A_{n+1}\;$ instead?