# continuation of problem subgroup isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

This subject is associated with
[Does group $A_6$ contain subgroup isomorphic with $S_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919168/does-group-a-6-contain-subgroup-isomorphic-with-s-4)

> Hint: Take $S_4$ on the first four elements of the set permuted by
>   $A_6$. Some of these are odd permutations. Can you see an easy way to
>   convert them into even permutations which are contained in $A_6$? Can
>   you do this in a consistent way which doesn't disturb the $S_4$
>   structure?

I do my best to understand it.
Isomorphism is a function betwenn groups. In this case we would like to find subgroup of $A_6$ isomorphic to $S_4$.

$A_6$ work with $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and all of permutations are even.
You give me a hint. 
I get any of permutation in $S_4$, for example $(13)(24)$.
Thus, when I work on firstly four elements:
We get:
$(13)(24)(5)(6)$

Is it what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, and for an odd permutation, like $(1,2) \in S_4$, you take $(1,2)(5,6) \in A_6$.

Comment: I take $(1,2)$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and I get: $(1,2)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)$ Why did you wrote: $(1,2)(5,6)$ ?

Comment: @xawey First, you wrote the 2 twice. Second, what are the parities of those things?

Answer (score 3):

We claim that:
$$
H = A_4 \cup \{(5,6)\alpha \mid \alpha \in S_4 \setminus A_4 \}
$$
is our desired subgroup. To see this, first we need to show that $H \leq A_6$:

- $\boxed{\emptyset \neq H \subseteq A_6}$: Can you see why each element of $H$ is an even permutation?
- $\boxed{\alpha,\beta \in H \implies \alpha^{-1}\beta \in H}$: Can you see why the composition of any two permutations in $H$ will either be in $A_4$ or have the form $(5,6)\alpha$ for some odd $\alpha$?

We also need to show that the function $f\colon S_4 \to H$ defined by:
$$
f(\alpha) = \begin{cases}
\alpha &\text{if } \alpha \in A_4 \\
(5,6)\alpha &\text{if } \alpha \in S_4 \setminus A_4 \\
\end{cases}
$$
is an isomorphism:

- $\boxed{f \text{ preserves structure}}$: Can you see why $f(\alpha)f(\beta) = f(\alpha\beta)$?
- $\boxed{f \text{ is injective}}$: Can you see why $f(\alpha) = f(\beta) \implies \alpha = \beta$?
- $\boxed{f \text{ is surjective}}$: This follows immediately by construction.

Comment: "Can you see why each element of $H$ is an even permutation?"  - Yes  "Can you see why the composition of any two permutations in H will either be in $A_4$ or have the form $(5,6)α$ for some odd $α$?" - No                  Rest of questions I'm thinking now.